# ASP.NET MVC 3 Custom Authentication/Authorization

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, authorization

I have searched all over the internet and SO, and I have found some good stuff on this topic, but I have a few questions that I am still unsure about:

1) I am using Forms Authentication with a custom Authentication provider. So I use the `Authorize` attribute and the section in the web.config still, but basically when the `FormsAuthenticationTicket` does not exist, I redirect to a login page (specified in the web.config) which then utilizes the custom Authentication Provider to auth the user against a db and then issues the `FormsAuthenticationTicket`. Is this correct?

2) Should I be using a custom `Authorize` attribute or should I just inject a `GenericPrincipal` into the `HttpContext` from the `Application_AuthenticateRequest` event handler in the global.asax page? Or should I be using `User.IsInRole` insode of the controller actions?

I just need role based authorization, and I think my Authentication Scheme is pretty good.

Any pointers/advice?

Thanks,
Sam

**Edit**

So from what I have read, the best option for this is to create a custom `AuthorizeAttribute` and override the `AuthorizeCore`.

So what I have done is this:

```
public class CustomAuthorize : System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            if (httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var model = AdminUserViewModel.FromJsonString(((FormsIdentity)httpContext.User.Identity).Ticket.UserData);
                httpContext.User = new GenericPrincipal(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity, model.SecurityGroups.Select(x => x.Name).ToArray());
            }
            return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        }

        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            //base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
            filterContext.Result = new System.Web.Mvc.RedirectResult("/Authentication/NotAuthorized", false);
        }
    }
```

Simply inject a new principal/identity with the roles that are stored in the `FormsAuthenticationTicket` `UserData` property. Then let the base do the rest.

Does this seem to be OK?

**Edit #2**

I am a little weary of using the `Application_AuthenticateRequest` in the global.asax with IIS7, because of the integrated pipeline, every request fires that event, images, css, js...

Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) I do the same thing.

2) I use Authorize attribute and Application_AuthenticateRequest event handler.

In Application_AuthenticateRequest event handler I do something like this:

```
    string[] roles = authenticationTicket.UserData.Split(',');

    if (Context.User != null)
        Context.User = new GenericPrincipal(Context.User.Identity, roles);
```

And at controller or action level I do something like this:

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin, SuperAdmin")]
```

Comment: How do you redirect to a action/view if they fail authorization?

Comment: Figured that out, just override the `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` in the custom `AuthorizeAttribute`.